# Are Bias-Variance trade-off and Mean Squared Prediction Error (MSPE) the same?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, forecasting, terminology

I was reading about the Bias-Variance trade-off in the textbook "Elements of statistical learning". Is the expected forecast error listed there the same as the MSPE?

[image]

Comment: Did you skim the wikipedia articles on MSPE and bias-variance trade-off?

Comment: Yes, but I am still not sure.